# Convert Redshift Super Array of String values to a comma separated string

Tags: arrays, type-conversion, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions, super

I have values in Redshift that are super data types and look like `["a", "b", "c"]`.

I'm trying to write a function like `array_join` in Athena SQL where it combines all the pieces with a separator. So for the example above, it would return a varchar value of `a, b, c`.

I have permission to create python/sql user defined functions if needed but python UDFs can't read in super data types.
I've tried converting the array to a subquery table and use partiql to unnest but redshift doesn't let me unnest the subquery on leader or something. My approach there is to then listagg the values back together. I was able to make a table instead of the subquery and unnest/listagg the values successfully but sql functions don't allow multi-commands.

I've also tried splitting the sql array into rows by using guides online involving a seq_0_5 view and adjusting the code to super functions. This didn't work because redshift disconnects me when I try to join tables using an inequality.

Let me know if I'm getting close but it feels like I've hit 2 dead-ends.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone runs into this problem, I found the solution! There is a json function called `json_serialize` that converts the super to a string. Then you just need to trim off the brackets and maybe replace out the double quotes.

Comment: all these functions have redshift max varchar limit which is troublesome with long jsons

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised there's not a function that does this. A cleaner approach than serializing and parsing text is to pivot the super array into a table long-ways then `listagg` back into a string list with the delimiter you want. I used this to get a pipe-delimited list.

Example table called `my_table`:

```
| id | my_array  |
|123 | ['a','b'] |
|234 | ['b','c'] |
```

And here's the SQL code using a semi-colon delimiter.

```
with array_long as (
    select t.*, arr
    from my_table t, t.my_array arr
)
select id, listagg(arr::varchar, ';') as my_array_list
from array_long
```

The result should look like this:

```
| id  | my_array_list |
| 123 | a;b           |
| 234 | b;c           |
```

[Here's the Redshift documentation on pivoting super arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html) if you need more complex examples